# Bootstrap - center child when parent isn't centered or full width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So i have this little layout being built with Bootstrap 4.6, and im trying to center the header, columns\cards & button to the page (width), when its parent container is left aligned and not full width.

Additionally, could anyone help with the svg image (the dots in the image im trying to make it look like) which aren't appearing.

an image of what i currently have (the image is full page width on a 1920x1080 screen)
[image]

How im trying to make it approx look like (this was built with TailWind CSS by a 3rd party)
[image]

```css
.related-box {
  width: 88% !important;
}

.related-box::before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg width='220' height='98' viewBox='0 0 220 98' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3e %3cellipse cx='93.0226' cy='92.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 93.0226 92.5)' fill='%23252932'/%3e %3cellipse cx='93.0226' cy='34.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 93.0226 34.5)' fill='%23252932'/%3e %3cellipse cx='93.0226' cy='63.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 93.0226 63.5)' fill='%23252932'/%3e %3cellipse cx='93.0226' cy='5.50002' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 93.0226 5.50002)' fill='%23252932'/%3e %3cellipse cx='63.8586' cy='92.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 63.8586 92.5)' fill='%23252932'/%3e %3cellipse cx='63.8586' cy='34.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 63.8586 34.5)' fill='%23252932'/%3e %3cellipse cx='63.8586' cy='63.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 63.8586 63.5)' fill='%23252932'/%3e %3cellipse cx='63.8586' cy='5.50002' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 63.8586 5.50002)' fill='%23252932'/%3e %3cellipse cx='34.6945' cy='92.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 34.6945 92.5)' fill='%23252932'/%3e %3cellipse cx='34.6945' cy='34.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 34.6945 34.5)' fill='%23252932'/%3e %3cellipse cx='34.6945' cy='63.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 34.6945 63.5)' fill='%23252932'/%3e %3cellipse cx='34.6945' cy='5.50002' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 34.6945 5.50002)' fill='%23252932'/%3e %3cellipse cx='5.53045' cy='92.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 5.53045 92.5)' fill='%23252932'/%3e %3cellipse cx='5.53045' cy='34.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 5.53045 34.5)' fill='%23252932'/%3e %3cellipse cx='5.53045' cy='63.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 5.53045 63.5)' fill='%23252932'/%3e %3cellipse cx='5.53045' cy='5.50003' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 5.53045 5.50003)' fill='%23252932'/%3e %3cellipse cx='213.7' cy='92.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 213.7 92.5)' fill='%23252932' fill-opacity='0.1'/%3e %3cellipse cx='213.7' cy='34.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 213.7 34.5)' fill='%23252932' fill-opacity='0.1'/%3e %3cellipse cx='213.7' cy='63.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 213.7 63.5)' fill='%23252932' fill-opacity='0.1'/%3e %3cellipse cx='213.7' cy='5.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 213.7 5.5)' fill='%23252932' fill-opacity='0.1'/%3e %3cellipse cx='184.536' cy='92.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 184.536 92.5)' fill='%23252932' fill-opacity='0.25'/%3e %3cellipse cx='184.536' cy='34.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 184.536 34.5)' fill='%23252932' fill-opacity='0.25'/%3e %3cellipse cx='184.536' cy='63.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 184.536 63.5)' fill='%23252932' fill-opacity='0.25'/%3e %3cellipse cx='184.536' cy='5.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 184.536 5.5)' fill='%23252932' fill-opacity='0.25'/%3e %3cellipse cx='155.372' cy='92.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 155.372 92.5)' fill='%23252932' fill-opacity='0.5'/%3e %3cellipse cx='155.372' cy='34.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 155.372 34.5)' fill='%23252932' fill-opacity='0.5'/%3e %3cellipse cx='155.372' cy='63.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 155.372 63.5)' fill='%23252932' fill-opacity='0.5'/%3e %3cellipse cx='155.372' cy='5.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 155.372 5.5)' fill='%23252932' fill-opacity='0.5'/%3e %3cellipse cx='126.209' cy='92.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 126.209 92.5)' fill='%23252932' fill-opacity='0.85'/%3e %3cellipse cx='126.209' cy='34.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 126.209 34.5)' fill='%23252932' fill-opacity='0.85'/%3e %3cellipse cx='126.209' cy='63.5' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 126.209 63.5)' fill='%23252932' fill-opacity='0.85'/%3e %3cellipse cx='126.209' cy='5.50002' rx='5.53107' ry='5.5' transform='rotate(180 126.209 5.50002)' fill='%23252932' fill-opacity='0.85'/%3e %3c/svg%3e");
  top: -18px;
  left: auto;
  right: -50px;
  width: 220px;
}

.bg-ceda-light {
  --bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgba(243, 243, 243, var(--bg-opacity));
  border-color: rgba(243, 243, 243, var(--bg-opacity));
  ;
}

.b-heading-2,
.fr-view h2 {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  line-height: 1.35
}

.b-heading-4,
.fr-view h4 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.25rem
}

.b-heading-6,
.fr-view h6 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: .75rem
}

.card-ceda-white {
  background-color: var(--white);
  border-color: var(--white);
  /* When Hover off */
  transition: 100ms ease;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 100ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  /******************/
}

.card-ceda-white-footer {
  border-top: none !important;
  /* border-color: none; */
  background-color: var(--white);
}

.card-ceda-white:hover {
  color: var(--white) !important;
  background-color: var(--ceda-darkblue);
  border-color: var(--ceda-darkblue);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.10);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.10);
  /* Safari */
  transform: scale(1.10);
  transition: 100ms ease;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 100ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card-ceda-white:hover .card-ceda-white-footer {
  background-color: var(--ceda-darkblue);
  color: var(--white);
}

.card-ceda-white:hover .btn-card-ceda-white {
  background-color: var(--ceda-darkblue);
  border-color: var(--white);
  color: var(--white);
}

.btn-card-ceda-white {
  color: var(--ceda-darkblue);
  border-color: var(--ceda-darkblue);
  background-color: var(--white);
  /* For when Hover off */
  transition: 100ms ease;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 100ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  /**********************/
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid pt-3 pl-0 pr-0">
  <div class="container-fluid related-box bg-ceda-light float-left">
    <h2 class="b-heading-2 text-center text-uppercase mb-5 mt-5">Related content title</h2>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-xs-10 pb-4">
        <div class="card card-ceda-white text-ceda-darkblue">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h6 class="b-heading-6 card-subtitle text-ceda-red text-uppercase pb-2">subheadline</h6>
            <h4 class="b-heading-4 card-title">headline</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Morbi ultricies, lorem et eleifend fermentum, eros nunc pretium nunc, bibendum ornare justo lacus sed ipsum. Aenean tincidunt enim quam, sit amet rhoncus orci gravida a. Donec dolor elit, gravida quis risus eu, viverra dignissim quam. Maecenas
              luctus, diam at venenatis molestie, erat nisl condimentum metus, lobortis laoreet sapien velit eu nisi.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer card-ceda-white-footer">
            <a class="btn btn-card-ceda-white text-uppercase" href="#">call to action</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-xs-10 pb-4">
        <div class="card card-ceda-white text-ceda-darkblue h-100">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h6 class="b-heading-6 card-subtitle text-ceda-red text-uppercase pb-2">subheadline</h6>
            <h4 class="b-heading-4 card-title">headline</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Morbi ultricies, lorem et eleifend fermentum, eros nunc pretium nunc, bibendum ornare justo lacus sed ipsum. Aenean tincidunt enim quam, sit amet rhoncus orci gravida a. </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer card-ceda-white-footer">
            <a class="btn btn-card-ceda-white text-uppercase" href="#">call to action</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-xs-10 pb-4">
        <div class="card card-ceda-white text-ceda-darkblue h-100">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h6 class="b-heading-6 card-subtitle text-ceda-red text-uppercase pb-2">subheadline</h6>
            <h4 class="b-heading-4 card-title">headline</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Morbi ultricies, lorem et eleifend fermentum, eros nunc pretium nunc, bibendum ornare justo lacus sed ipsum. </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer card-ceda-white-footer">
            <a class="btn btn-card-ceda-white text-uppercase" href="#">call to action</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--<div class="row">-->
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center pt-3 pb-4">
      <a class="btn btn-ceda-darkblue-outline text-center text-uppercase" href="#">view more</a>
    </div>
    <!--</div>-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe there is something missing in your code, because when I tried to replicate it in CodePen, it didn't look like the images you sent.

Comment: It wouldn't display the Red\Green\Blue bars you see at the very top of my image, as those are a part of something else (so HTML not included) - but otherwise its built with Bootstrap 4.6 and my additional CSS really just style text & cards except for the class `.related-box` which defines the width of the grey background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you want to center your content, you have to give the gray box an equal space on its left. Looking at the image from your designer, it looks like they want a 17% white space on the right. To duplicate the space on the left, I’ve added a division that’s 79.52% of the remaining space (one minus the 17% white space divided by the 83% gray space = 1 – 17/83 = 79.52%). Then you can put a new container inside that centered div with your cards.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>
    .related-box {
        width: 83% !important;
    }

    .related-box::before {
        content: '';
        background: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
        top: -11px;
        left: auto;
        right: 12.15%;
        width: 220px;
        height: 110px;
        position: absolute;
        background-size: 220px 110px;
    }

    .bg-ceda-light {
        --bg-opacity: 1;
        background-color: rgba(243, 243, 243, var(--bg-opacity));
        border-color: rgba(243, 243, 243, var(--bg-opacity));
        ;
    }

    .b-heading-2,
    .fr-view h2 {
        font-size: 1.75rem;
        line-height: 1.35
    }

    .b-heading-4,
    .fr-view h4 {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 1.25rem
    }

    .b-heading-6,
    .fr-view h6 {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: .75rem
    }

    .card-ceda-white {
        background-color: var(--white);
        border-color: var(--white);
        /* When Hover off */
        transition: 100ms ease;
        transition-property: all;
        transition-duration: 100ms;
        transition-timing-function: ease;
        transition-delay: 0s;
        /******************/
    }

    .card-ceda-white-footer {
        border-top: none !important;
        /* border-color: none; */
        background-color: var(--white);
    }


    .card-ceda-white:hover {
        color: var(--white) !important;
        background-color: var(--ceda-darkblue);
        border-color: var(--ceda-darkblue);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.10);
        /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.10);
        /* Safari */
        transform: scale(1.10);
        transition: 100ms ease;
        transition-property: all;
        transition-duration: 100ms;
        transition-timing-function: ease;
        transition-delay: 0s;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .card-ceda-white:hover .card-ceda-white-footer {
        background-color: var(--ceda-darkblue);
        color: var(--white);
    }

    .card-ceda-white:hover .btn-card-ceda-white {
        background-color: var(--ceda-darkblue);
        border-color: var(--white);
        color: var(--white);
    }

    .btn-card-ceda-white {
        color: var(--ceda-darkblue);
        border-color: var(--ceda-darkblue);
        background-color: var(--white);
        /* For when Hover off */
        transition: 100ms ease;
        transition-property: all;
        transition-duration: 100ms;
        transition-timing-function: ease;
        transition-delay: 0s;
        /**********************/
    }
</style>

<div class="container-fluid pt-3 pl-0 pr-0">
    <div class="container-fluid related-box bg-ceda-light float-left">
        <div style="width: 79.52%; float: right;">
            <h2 class="b-heading-2 text-center text-uppercase mb-5 mt-5">Related content title</h2>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 pb-4">
                        <div class="card card-ceda-white text-ceda-darkblue">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h6 class="b-heading-6 card-subtitle text-ceda-red text-uppercase pb-2">subheadline</h6>
                                <h4 class="b-heading-4 card-title">headline</h4>
                                <p class="card-text">Morbi ultricies, lorem et eleifend fermentum, eros nunc pretium nunc, bibendum ornare justo lacus sed ipsum. Aenean tincidunt enim quam,
                                    sit amet rhoncus orci gravida a. Donec dolor elit, gravida quis risus eu, viverra dignissim quam. Maecenas luctus, diam at venenatis molestie, erat nisl
                                    condimentum metus, lobortis laoreet sapien velit eu nisi.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer card-ceda-white-footer">
                                <a class="btn btn-card-ceda-white text-uppercase" href="#">call to action</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 pb-4">
                        <div class="card card-ceda-white text-ceda-darkblue h-100">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h6 class="b-heading-6 card-subtitle text-ceda-red text-uppercase pb-2">subheadline</h6>
                                <h4 class="b-heading-4 card-title">headline</h4>
                                <p class="card-text">Morbi ultricies, lorem et eleifend fermentum, eros nunc pretium nunc, bibendum ornare justo lacus sed ipsum. Aenean tincidunt enim quam,
                                    sit amet rhoncus orci gravida a. </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer card-ceda-white-footer">
                                <a class="btn btn-card-ceda-white text-uppercase" href="#">call to action</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 pb-4">
                        <div class="card card-ceda-white text-ceda-darkblue h-100">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h6 class="b-heading-6 card-subtitle text-ceda-red text-uppercase pb-2">subheadline</h6>
                                <h4 class="b-heading-4 card-title">headline</h4>
                                <p class="card-text">Morbi ultricies, lorem et eleifend fermentum, eros nunc pretium nunc, bibendum ornare justo lacus sed ipsum. </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer card-ceda-white-footer">
                                <a class="btn btn-card-ceda-white text-uppercase" href="#">call to action</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--<div class="row">-->
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center pt-3 pb-4">
                <a class="btn btn-ceda-darkblue-outline text-center text-uppercase" href="#">view more</a>
            </div>
            <!--</div>-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don’t know about SVG, so I threw together a PNG file and then embedded it as a base64 image so you can see the effect. Also, I didn’t make any adjustment for your dots for a small screen, but it seems to match your image for a large screen.

Your code was using `col-xs-10` — xs is from Bootstrap 3, but your tag says Bootstrap 4, so I switched your column styles.